# SQL/JAVA Hotel Cost calculation System

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to find the cost of a room by taking in the BookingID, but to do this I need to find the Room ID which matches the Booking ID, I am quite confused about getting this to work. i know I will have to structure my DB differently to get this to work but I'm not sure how to do this . Any suggestions will be deeply appreciated as this is a homework assignment.

Here is my  Java code where I am trying to collect information from DB to carry out calculations:

```
public void calculateInvoice( int inputID )
   {
       try
       {
           System.err.println( this.getClass().getName()+ ":: DB connected := " + dbSession.isConnected() ) ;

           sql = "SELECT RoomCost"
                   + " FROM Room"
                   + " WHERE RoomID = " + inputID ;

           sql = "SELECT DATEDIFF(Check_Out , Check_In) AS DaysBooked"
               + " WHERE RoomID = " + inputID ;
                   + " FROM Assign " ;

           sqlStatement = dbSession.getConnection().createStatement() ;
           resultSet = sqlStatement.executeQuery( sql ) ;
           resultSet.next() ;

           int iDaysBooked = resultSet.getInt( "DaysBooked" ) ;
     
           System.out.println("Days stayed" + iDaysBooked);

           resultSet.close() ;
       }
       catch( SQLException se )
       {
           System.err.println( this.getClass().getName() + ":: SQL error:: " + se ) ;
           se.printStackTrace() ;
       }
       catch ( Exception e )
       {
           System.err.println( this.getClass().getName() + ":: Error:: " + e ) ;
           e.printStackTrace() ;
       }
       finally
       {
       }
       return ;
   }
```

DB code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS   Assign ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS   Bookings ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS   Customer ;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS   Room ;


-- Create Customers Table

CREATE TABLE myWork.Customer 
(
        CustomerID      INT             NOT NULL       UNIQUE     AUTO_INCREMENT ,
        Surname         CHAR( 30 )      NOT NULL ,
        FirstName       CHAR( 30 )      NOT NULL ,
        Title           CHAR( 10 ) ,
        DOB             DATE            NOT NULL , 
        HouseNumber     CHAR( 4 )       NOT NULL ,
        StreetName      CHAR( 30 )      NOT NULL ,
        Town            CHAR( 30 ) ,
        PostCode        CHAR( 9 )       NOT NULL ,
        Telephone       INT             NOT NULL ,
        PRIMARY KEY ( CustomerID )
) ;

-- Create Bookings Table

CREATE TABLE myWork.Bookings
(
        BookingID       INT              NOT NULL       UNIQUE    AUTO_INCREMENT ,
        CustomerID      INT              NOT NULL ,
        AdultsBooked    INT              NOT NULL ,
        ChildrenBooked  INT              NOT NULL ,
        Check_In        DATE  ,
        Check_Out       DATE  ,
        DaysBooked      INT   ,
        PRIMARY KEY ( BookingID ) ,
        FOREIGN KEY ( CustomerID ) REFERENCES myWork.Customer( CustomerID )
) ;

-- Create Rooms Table

CREATE TABLE myWork.Room
(
        RoomID           INT              NOT NULL       UNIQUE    AUTO_INCREMENT ,
        RoomNumber       INT              NOT NULL ,
        Occupancy        INT              NOT NULL ,
        RoomType         CHAR(15)         NOT NULL ,
        Shower           CHAR(1)          NOT NULL ,
        Jacuzzi          CHAR(1)          NOT NULL ,
        SeaView          CHAR(1)          NOT NULL ,
        HoneyMoon        CHAR(1)          NOT NULL ,
        FamilyRoom       CHAR(1)          NOT NULL ,
        RoomFloor        INT              NOT NULL ,
        RoomCost         INT              NOT NULL ,
        StatusCleaned    CHAR(1)          NOT NULL ,
        StatusAvailable  CHAR(1)          NOT NULL ,
        PRIMARY KEY ( RoomID )
) ;

CREATE TABLE myWork.Assign
(
        AssignID        INT              NOT NULL       UNIQUE    AUTO_INCREMENT ,
        RoomID          INT              NOT NULL ,
        BookingID       INT              NOT NULL ,
        PRIMARY KEY (AssignID ) , 
        FOREIGN KEY (BookingID ) REFERENCES myWork.Bookings( BookingID ) ,
        FOREIGN KEY (RoomID ) REFERENCES myWork.Room( RoomID )

) ;


SELECT * FROM Customer ;
SELECT * FROM Bookings ;
SELECT * FROM Room ;
SELECT * FROM Assign ;
```

Comment: Try SELECT * FROM BOOKINGS INNER JOIN ASSIGN ON BOOKINGS.BOOKINGID = ASSING.ASSIGNID INNER JOIN ROOM ON ASSIGN.ROOMID = ROOM.ROOMID

Comment: You can do it with one query using joins (comment above) and it is the way to go. However, if you are not familiar with that concept, you can also make two different queries that you execute one after the other. The first one is a simple `SELECT` from the table `Assign`, which returns the `roomID` for a specific `bookingID`.  (Your DB model is designed to have multiple `roomID` per booking. Possibly, you have to handle that case too.) Afterwards, you use the `roomID` in the second query, which is exactly the first query in your code.